# Using for loop to make multiple drawLine shapes

Tags: java, graphics

I am making a star using a draw line. I want to run a for loop to expand a star into multiple stars in a grid-like pattern. I am fairly new to java and could use some help with my code. The gride pattern that I would like the stars to open up too isn't too specific as far as columns x rows go. even making 6 stars or 9 stars is fine, as long as they are in a grid-like pattern.

So far, I have the star drawn with drawLine. At one point I got two stars but they were to close to each other. When I run the code it looks like I have a whole bunch of stars sort of staggered on top of each other and being able to get two stars on Star Field, I would like to get more in such 5x6 pattern or something close. I believe I might be having a hard time computing the math in the for loops to get this to happen.

Should I run, multiple nested for loops or is there a way to do this with using a minimal amount of for loops?

```
public static void drawFlag(int stars, int stripes, java.awt.Graphics 
g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
// Sets backround rectangle color to white
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

// Draw filled red rectangles *stripes*
int stripeHeight = height/stripes;
g.setColor(Color.RED);
int lastStripeDrawnY = 0;
// For loop runs red stripes
for (int i = y; i < y + height - 2*stripeHeight; i = i + 2*stripeHeight) 
{ 
g.fillRect(x, i, width, stripeHeight);
lastStripeDrawnY = i;
}
    // expands strips across the rectangle
    int lastStripeY = lastStripeDrawnY+2*stripeHeight;
    int lastStripeHeight = y + height - lastStripeY;
    if (stripes%2 != 0) {
    g.fillRect(x, lastStripeY, width, lastStripeHeight);
            }   

    int stars1 = 15; 
    for (int cols = 1; cols  <= stars1; cols++) {
    int rows = stars1/cols;
    if (cols > rows && cols <2*rows && cols*rows == stars1) {

}
}
            // Draws the starField
    int numberOfRedStripes = (int)Math.ceil(stripes/2.0);
    int starFieldHeight = numberOfRedStripes*stripeHeight;
    int starFieldWidth = starFieldHeight*width/height;
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, starFieldWidth, starFieldHeight);


for (int x1 = 0; x1+100 <+ starFieldWidth-5; x1++) {
    if(x1/5*4 == stars) {
        drawStar(g,x1,y,50);
    for(int y1 = 0; y1 <=starFieldHeight-5;y1++) {
                if(y1/4*2 == stars) {
        drawStar(g,x,y1,50);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
        // drawLine the star
public static void drawStar(java.awt.Graphics g, int x, int y, int size) 
{
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.drawLine(x+size/2, y+size/6, x+4*size/5, y+5*size/6);
g.drawLine(x+4*size/5,y+5*size/6, x+size/6, y+2*size/5);
g.drawLine(x+size/6, y+2*size/5, x+5*size/6, y+2*size/5);
g.drawLine(x+5*size/6, y+2*size/5, x+size/5, y+5*size/6);
g.drawLine(x+size/5, y+5*size/6, x+size/2, y+size/6); 
}
}
```

Expand one star into a checkered grid-like pattern.

Comment: Code formatting matters -- please don't make it harder for someone to read and understand your code than it has to be. Please [edit] your question and format the code for consistency and readability.

Comment: For better, sooner help, post [mcve]. And add an image/sketch of the expected output. That will help us to understand your code and requirement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used your `drawStar()` function and built this `StarPanel`. Try it and see if it gives you some hints for what you are trying to achieve.

Note that I removed `g.setColor(Color.WHITE);` line from your `drawStar()` function. We need to be careful when we set color of `Graphics` object. In many cases, this is the reason why we don't see what we draw.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class StarPanel extends JPanel
{
  private int xStarting;
  private int yStarting;

  private int numberOfRows;
  private int numberOfColumns;

  private int xDisplacement;
  private int yDisplacement;

  public StarPanel(int xStarting, int yStarting,
                   int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns,
                   int xDisplacement, int yDisplacement)
  {
    this.xStarting = xStarting;
    this.yStarting = yStarting;
    this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
    this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    this.xDisplacement = xDisplacement;
    this.yDisplacement = yDisplacement;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    StarPanel starPanel = new StarPanel(50, 50, 5, 6, 75, 75);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(starPanel);
    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 500, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
        drawStar(g, xStarting + (row * xDisplacement), yStarting + (column * yDisplacement), 50);
      }
    }
  }

  // drawLine the star
  public static void drawStar(java.awt.Graphics g, int x, int y, int size)
  {
    g.drawLine(x+size/2, y+size/6, x+4*size/5, y+5*size/6);
    g.drawLine(x+4*size/5,y+5*size/6, x+size/6, y+2*size/5);
    g.drawLine(x+size/6, y+2*size/5, x+5*size/6, y+2*size/5);
    g.drawLine(x+5*size/6, y+2*size/5, x+size/5, y+5*size/6);
    g.drawLine(x+size/5, y+5*size/6, x+size/2, y+size/6);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So far I have been able to fill in the starField but now I have too many stars. I will check this out and keep playing with this. Washington state got snowed in today so I am also hoping I don't lose power now.

Comment: is there a way I can update my code here?

Comment: @Woop, yes, use the `edit` button in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can approach this problem, you can, as you've started, simply try and build each star individually based on the required x/y position.

You could make a single star that was always at `0x0` and `translate` the `Graphics` context to the desire `x/y` position

Or, you could take advantage of the `Shape` API.

This allows you to define a self contained object which describes the shape you are trying to create.

```
public class StarShape extends Path2D.Double {

    public StarShape(double size) {
        double mid = size / 2d;
        moveTo(mid, 0);

        lineTo((size * 0.6d), (size * 0.4d));
        lineTo(size, (size * 0.4d));

        lineTo((size * 0.72d), (size * 0.58d));
        lineTo((size * 0.85d), size);

        lineTo((size * 0.5d), (size * 0.72d));

        lineTo((size * 0.2), size);
        lineTo((size * 0.325d), (size * 0.58d));

        lineTo(0, (size * 0.4d));
        lineTo((size * 0.4d), (size * 0.4d));
        closePath();
    }

}
```

There are lots of side benefits to this, but the immediate benefit is that it's "paintable".  You can pass an instance of it directly to `Graphics2D` and have it painted and/or filled based on your needs.

Now, with that in hand, you can do something like...

[image: Stars]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private StarShape star;
    private double starSize = 10;;

    public TestPane() {
        star = new StarShape(starSize);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        double y = 0;
        for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < getHeight() / starSize; yIndex++) {
            double x = 0;
            for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < getWidth() / starSize; xIndex++) {
                AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
                PathIterator path = star.getPathIterator(at);

                GeneralPath p = new GeneralPath();
                p.append(path, true);

                g2d.fill(p);
                x += starSize;
            }
            y += starSize;
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

The reason I'd prefer this method, is it doesn't affect the origin of the original `starShape`.  You could also use the technique to cache the results, so you're not repeatedly doing it in the `paintComponent` method.

You could also do something like...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    double y = 0;
    for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < getHeight() / starSize; yIndex++) {
        double x = 0;
        for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < getWidth() / starSize; xIndex++) {
            Graphics2D starg = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            starg.translate(x, y);
            starg.fill(star);
            starg.dispose();
            x += starSize;
        }
        y += starSize;
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Which changes the origin of the `Graphics` context instead or something like...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    double xCount = getWidth() / starSize;
    for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < getHeight() / starSize; yIndex++) {
        for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < getWidth() / starSize; xIndex++) {
            g2d.fill(star);
            star.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(starSize, 0));
        }
        star.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-(starSize) * xCount, starSize));
    }
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

which changes the origin of the `star` itself.

Personally, I prefer not to affect the original and instead simply change the context in how it's painted, but which method you use will come down to your needs.

Okay, that might seem like a lot of work for little gain, but the `Shape`s API is extremely powerful.  Because it's point based (instead of pixel based), it can be more easily resized, without generating pixilation.  It's very simple to rotate, through the use of `AffineTransform` and makes for a much simpler point of re-use.

Want to make the stars bigger?  Simply change `starStar`, for example...

```
private double starSize = 50;
```

and the API takes care of the rest...

[image: Upsize]